# Specific styles.xml resources for mdpi devices Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I'd like to provide different styles for mdpi devices and need a suggestion for the best way of doing this. The problem I'm having is that large dpi devices prioritise mdpi qualifier instead of the default values.

For example, the app has the following resource structure:

```
res/
  values/styles.xml
  values-mdpi/styles.xml
```

The idea here is to provide an alternative style for smaller screen devices. But it looks like Android chooses mdpi styles for larger dpi devices as the qualifier is working on the bases of minimum supported dpi.

Ideally I'd like to avoid providing styles.xml for every possible dpi as I use flavors and adding 4 new styles.xml would be multiplied by the number of flavors so change in one styles.xml would mean a change in a lot of files...

Is there an easier way to provide a specific resource for mdpi devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no other way for you to provide at least two `styles.xml`:

```
res/
  values-mdpi/styles.xml
  values-hdpi/styles.xml
```

The former is for mdpi or smaller dpi.
The latter is for hdpi or larger dpi.

Comment: 2 is ok - I'm good with just 2. I think it's a good solution. Do you know is it safe to remove the default styles.xml from value folder with no qualifier?

Comment: It should be safe. Though I have not tried with styles, I sometimes have drawable resources only in a specific drawables-***dpi folder without an error. From those existed resource folders the nearest one will be used. If you are anxious, you can test with emulators which have different dpis.